# Two domains, two Wordpress installations - do I need one or two databases?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Plesk on my CentOS server and I have two domains.

My first domain uses Wordpress.

Now I would like to use Wordpress on my second domain. I will install Wordpress second time.

Do I need to have a separate Wordpress database?

I'd like to keep these two domains separate as much as possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use two seperate databases for two seperate databases. It doesn't use any more resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep those two sites as separate as possible, you should go for the two database-setup.

Technically it's perfectly working with just one, as long as you change the db-prefix-setting during the install or in the wp-config.php.

I'd recommend you to do a full database-backup BEFORE messing around with the prefixes...

Comment: Created a separate database for each site. Works nice.

Answer (score 2):

You could of course transform the first Wordpress installation and into a MultiUser Setup:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

This would give you the possibility of managing both instances from one backend.

And of course you would in this case only be using one DB.